# IE 11 CORS https to http fails

Tags: cors, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to call a http local service on port 8080 from our web app which is https through Ajax. IE11.0.9600.17691 continuously gives a Access is denied error. The call I make from the HTTPS page is like http://127.0.0.1:8080/functionname.

I have seen people being able to do this type of call(https to http), however I have never been able to get a success. I have put a breakpoint in Developer tools and the local http server is never even called. There is no pre-flight request too. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My version of jquery is jquery/1.10.2. Our http server has the requisite Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST, OPTIONS and the access control allow origin is also set to the correct url.

I have seen posts similar to this and have enabled Access Sources across domains and allow mixed content.

Comment: There's not a lot of information that we can go off of to help you out here...notably, we don't know what kind of server you're calling, or if you've got a firewall up.  Providing some context in terms of error messages would go a long way to helping clarify this question.

Comment: It is a .net 4.0 service, installed on the local machine listening on port 8080, I disabled the firewall and it is still the same. If I make the call as https then the Access denied goes away, but we want to keep it as http.

Comment: Anything else I am missing?? Can we accomplish this through any other means? https to http?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE11 CORS rejecting OPTIONS on https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882037/ie11-cors-rejecting-options-on-https)