# IE11 CORS rejecting OPTIONS on https

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, cors, internet-explorer-11

IE11 for some reason is rejecting a PUT request but only when I use https.
I have very hard time to find the issue as using http, localhost and other browsers works fine.

The console is showing two errors

```
SEC7124: Request method PUT was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods list.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

OPTION request sent from the browser is

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type, session-id
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT   
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Connection: Keep-Alive  
Content-Length: 0  
Host: api.domain.com  
Origin: https://portal.domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

and the response from the server is following:

```
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5
Server: server
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Session-Id
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: -1
Allow: OPTIONS,GET,HEAD,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, origin, Content-Type, session-id, authorization, portal-url
Content-Type: application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Content-Length: 352
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2016 15:33:38 GMT
```

AngularJS is used on client side standard $http PUT is used.
Java with jersey is used on server side and request filter to handle CORS is the following:

```
 public ContainerResponse filter( final ContainerRequest request, final ContainerResponse response )
{
    if ( request.getHeaderValue( "Origin" ) != null ) 
    {
        final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = response.getHttpHeaders();
        headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
        headers.add( "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Session-Id" );
        headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", Boolean.TRUE.toString() );
    }

    if ( "OPTIONS".equals( request.getMethod() ) ) 
    {
        final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = response.getHttpHeaders();
        for ( String method : ["OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"] ) 
        {
            headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method );
        }
        headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "accept, origin, Content-Type, session-id, authorization, portal-url, " 
                + "If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Pragma" );
        headers.add( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "-1" );            
    }

    return response;
}
```

Maybe you can see what may be wrong with that.

Thanks

Comment: try setting actual origin instead of `*`

Comment: Check IE console (F12 to open devtools) for the errors. There should be a message describing why the browser rejected the request. Out of the head - allow credentials=true should be accompanied by non-star allow origin.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin error message is right at top of OP question

Comment: @OlegEstekhin yes the error is SEC7124: Request method PUT was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods list.
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied. But how to avoid * in the response like api will be used as well from mobile devices and they do not have static origin

Comment: Try setting complete origin and not * as allow-origin header. Plus, only set PUT in allow-methods header. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to find the issue.

I saw this issue on https only because the portal and the host where on different domains. I could not replicate the issue on localhost because both the server and portal are on this same domain. This means the OPTION request was not sent and everything worked as expected. After running the portal on localhost and using IP address as a server URL instead of localhost the OPTION request was included in the request and I could replicate my issue.

And the issue it self was down to following code on the server

```
    for ( String method : ["OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"] ) 
    {
        headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method );
    }
```

for some reason IE did not like multiple `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers. After changing code to the following issue was solved.

```
 List<String> ALLOWED_METHODS = Arrays.asList( "OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE" );
 headers.add( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS );
```