# Microsoft Edge 14 options request response not received?

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, cors, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to load a JSON file from my CDN, and all browsers work except MS Edge. When I inspect the network tab of Edge, I see that the OPTIONS requests that preceed the request to the actual JSON file keep their "pending" status, and the response headers as well as the response body stay empty in that panel, as shown in the screenshot below :
[image: Response headers stay empty]

When I reload the page, the files that I was trying to fetch show up, before even my page request, and are shown to have taken many seconds to load (here, 3887 seconds) :
[image: Edge showing loaded files]

My server is definite that a 200 response was sent as a response to the initial OPTIONS request :

```
method: "OPTIONS"    
resource: "/lang/locale-survey-en_US.json?1490092072501"    
httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"    
status: 200    
responseSize: "175"    
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393"
```

My best guess is that Edge is not able to read the response to the OPTIONS request, but if so why would it send OPTIONS requests in the first place ? As it works in all other browsers, I'm out of ideas about how I can debug this, so if you have suggestions about which logs or what I should check, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882037/ie11-cors-rejecting-options-on-https & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176082/why-are-cors-requests-failing-in-microsoft-edge-but-working-in-other-browsers

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say in the original post that I don't have any error or warning in the console (which, I guess, means it's not a error on the CORS configuration).

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?

Comment: @pulekies unfortunately no, I haven't tested it since I had this problem, and my current workaround is to detect with JS if the browser is IE/Edge, and in case it is, I change my CDN url to my normal URL (so I don't use the CDN and don't need CORS)

Comment: I had an issue with just Edge requests being left in "(Pending)" and it turned out we had "Zero-width space" in our IIS HTTP Response Header.